# What's causing this Stack Overflow error when there is no infinite recursive method?

Tags: java, for-loop, arraylist, stack-overflow, infinite-loop

I am making a chess program in Java. I have a boolean method that takes the location that the user would like to move a rook to, in the form of two `int`s, and based on the rook's current row and column, determines if the rook can move there, using for loops. Here is one of the loops as an example.

```java
int nc = col - 1;
    while (nc >= 0){
    moves.add(new Integer[]{row, nc});
    if (locals[row][nc] != null)
        break;
    nc--;
}
```

`moves` is an ArrayList that I have declared earlier in the program. It stores a list of all the valid moves, and this is one of the for loops I use to instantiate it.

The issue is, each time I run this code, the lines that include the add methods are highlighted for being infinite loops, and the code will not run. What am I doing wrong?

**Edit**:

This is the exact error message that the software is showing me:

[image]

[image]

Additionally, I'm going to post the full text of the method. I'm not sure if any of it is relevant to my question, but it might prove helpful.

```java
public boolean isValidMove(int r, int c){
        Piece[][] locals = Chess.getBoard();
        if (r < 0 || c < 0 || r > 7 || c > 7 || (locals[r][c] != null && locals[r][c].getWhite() == isWhite))
            return false;
        ArrayList<Integer[]> moves = new ArrayList<Integer[]>();
        int nc = col - 1;
        while (nc >= 0){
            moves.add(new Integer[]{row, nc});
            if (locals[row][nc] != null)
                break;
            nc--;
        }
        nc = col + 1;
        while (nc < 8){
            moves.add(new Integer[]{row, nc});
            if (locals[row][nc] != null)
                break;
            nc++;
        }
        int nr = row - 1;
        while (nr >= 0){
            moves.add(new Integer[]{nr, col});
            if (locals[nr][col] != null)
                break;
            nr--;
        }
        nr = row + 1;
        while (nr < 8){
            moves.add(new Integer[]{nr, col});
            if (locals[nr][col] != null)
                break;
            nr++;
        }
        for (Integer[] ints : moves){
            if (ints[0] == r && ints[1] == c)
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Do the loops actually run infinitely?

Comment: Are you using an IDE? IntelliJ Idea usually detects things like infinite loops while you write your code and offers a solution. What's your IDE telling you when you hover the underline?

Comment: I suggest you remove unrelated code and information from the question, and only include snippets of where you think there is an infinite loop. In order to make the question more clear.

Comment: @Turing85, as far as I can tell, no.

Comment: Have you tried running your code in the debugger?

Comment: so... there is no  actual problem?

Comment: @CausingUnderflowsEverywhere, I'm not using an IDE. I'm learning to program in school, and I am writing the program in the editor we use on codehs.com. It highlights the line that error is occurring on and states what the nature of the error is, but it doesn't do much more than that. In this case, it highlighted the line with the add method, and said that it's an infinite loop, but it can't be, because that's not a loop to begin with. I checked the loop that it's in, but that's not infinite either.

Comment: @Turing85 I encounter a run time error while running the program, so I know something is wrong, but the loop in question is not running forever. By definition, because I used a "greater than" comparison operator, and because the loop control variable decrements, it can't be an infinite loop.

Comment: @ap please post the runtime error in your question.

Comment: @CausingUnderflowsEverywhere Sorry it took so long, I just got around to doing that.

Comment: Now I know why you came to Stack Overflow for help! It's a Stack Overflow error! :)

Comment: Can you show the full error of this one: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vKXNj.png this is just a small part of it.

Comment: @CausingUnderflowsEverywhere That's the whole thing. The rest is just a list of all the places the error is occurring in, and it's over 1000 lines long.

Comment: Yes, the rest of it with at least a couple recursions shown is very necessary to judge what is causing the infinite loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered what is wrong the program and managed to fix it. The loop in question does not in fact iterate forever, however a method somewhere in this program called another method which in turn called the original method. Hence, the Stack Overflow error without any *one* infinitely recursive method.